# Failing to load a resource in SFML 2.4

Tags: c++, resources, sfml

I'm using SFML 2.4 and Visual Studio Community 2015.
I am having trouble loading an image from a resource, and I cannot find anything.
Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

sf::Sprite m_Test;

sf::Image LoadImageFromResource(LPCWSTR name)
{
    HRSRC rsrcData = FindResource(NULL, name, RT_RCDATA);
    if (!rsrcData)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find resource.");

    DWORD rsrcDataSize = SizeofResource(NULL, rsrcData);
    if (rsrcDataSize <= 0) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Size of resource is 0.", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        throw std::runtime_error("Size of resource is 0.");
    }

    HGLOBAL grsrcData = LoadResource(NULL, rsrcData);
    if (!grsrcData)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load resource.");

    LPVOID firstByte = LockResource(grsrcData);
    if (!firstByte)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to lock resource.");

    sf::Image image;
    if (!image.loadFromMemory(firstByte, rsrcDataSize))
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load image from memory.");

    return image;
}

void init() {
    sf::Image testImage = LoadImageFromResource(L"test");
    sf::Texture testTexture;
    if (!testTexture.loadFromImage(testImage)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load image.");
    }

    sf::Sprite test;
    test.setTexture(testTexture);
    m_Test = test;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "The Principle of Battle");

    init();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        window.draw(m_Test);

        window.display();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the output says this:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF47BE7788 in The Principle of Battle.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0000009C0C96EE18.

I tried to debug it, but I couldn't. I cannot find an answer to this problem.

Comment: I will check it at home but... why don't you use "testTexture.loadFromFile" method from SFML?

Comment: Because I want to load it from a dll file

Comment: Oh, ok. You are right. I checked it at home. Unfortunatelly I have some other system errors so I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into exception handling if you are going to use exceptions. The error says an exception was thrown, so you need to find out what the exception is so you know what to fix.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Here is the issue, The size of the resource is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this line from:

```
HRSRC rsrcData = FindResource(NULL, name, RT_RCDATA);
```

to:

```
HRSRC rsrcData = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(name), RT_RCDATA);
```

Comment: But now I am getting a white image.